# Spark Dynamic allocation and number of executors in web UI

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am very new to Spark and for near real time I am using Spark Streaming and I am confused and not getting answer for this question `In Spark Web UI I am not seeing fixed number of executors always even I have enabled dynamic allocation` , How can I get accurate data for executors , so I can optimize my application further. And is there any open source monitoring tool for spark and spark streaming.

Comment: are you JSR29??

Comment: Please elaborate by giving a more detailed example and describe exactly what step you took and what didn't work as expected.

Comment: No , I am Akshay . but I saw same kind of question from other user.